# Access token is not getting printed in console in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, rest-client

I am trying to fetch gmail contacts. I gave the following URL in view:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:3000%2Fgmail&response_type=token&client_id=XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

In the controller when I put params.inspect the following got printed:

```
{"controller"=>"apicalls", "action"=>"gmail"}
```

Access token is not getting printed. But in the browser, the access token is could be seen.

```
http://localhost:3000/gmail#access_token=xxxxxxx&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

My question is how can I print this access token in my controller?

Comment: make sure that you're on the correct action and controller.  also make sure that you're not deleting the items in the params hash.  look at before_filters to see if any of them modify the params.

Comment: I am damn sure that, I'm in correct action and controller. Also I checked before filters too

Comment: ah i noticed something with the url.  it's using `#` instead of `?` which actually makes those params an anchor and not a parameter.  try going to `http://localhost:3000/gmail?access_token=xxxxxxx&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600` manually.

Comment: Yes. But, how can I edit it? It's redirected by google api.

Comment: no idea. it is actually weird that google redirects you to that url. there must have been a callback url setting somewhere which you can change and update.